# How to remove Yii2 redirect with ActiveForm and Pjax?

Tags: ajax, forms, yii2, pjax, active-form

i have problem with redirect after submitting form.

**The first: I have this form for subscribe users.**

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center">
                        <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'my-pjax']); ?>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'validationUrl' => 'validate',
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'mbr-form',
                    'data-pjax' => true,
                ],
        ]); ?>

        <div class="row row-sm-offset">
            <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'fio')->input('text', ['placeholder' => 'Иванов Иван Иванович'])->label('Ф.И.О',['class' => 'form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true])->input('email', ['placeholder' => 'ivanov.ivan@schoolofwriting.ru'])->label('Email', ['class' => 'form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="input-group-btn"><?= Html::submitButton('ЗАПИСАТЬСЯ', ['class' => 'btn btn-form btn-success display-4']) ?></span>

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**The second: I have controller with actions for form.**

```
public function actionFree()
    {
        $this->view->title = "ШКОЛА ПИСАТЕЛЬСКОГО МАСТЕРСТВА: Новичок рассказов";

        $model = new SubscribeForm();
        $password = $model->generateStrongPassword(12);
        $model->course = 1;
        $model->password = md5($password);

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            if ($model->save()) {

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Будущий писатель, вскоре ты получишь письмо с инструкцией!
                  Надеемся, что курс тебе понравится и мы продолжим обучение');
            }
            else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $model->errors);
            }
        }
        else {
            // страница отображается первый раз
            return $this->render('free-course', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

    public function actionValidate() {
        $model = new SubscribeForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }
```

**What i do?** I use the validation of the e-mail field so that it does not repeat and output the message under the form. Then i get POST data and save it to database inside controller. As a result i want to set FLASH MESSAGE and show it in current opened page without redirection and refreshes.

So.. **I always have refresh. Why?**

Comment: Set timeout  property to false in PJAX widget 
`Pjax::begin(['id' => 'my-pjax','timeout'=>false]);` 
and u have called `$model->save()`  twice it should be one time.

Comment: Thanks, i added `'timeout'=>false`, but it's not working... i have page refresh (

Comment: **Done** Omg, 3 days... FLASH MESSAGE was outside PJAX :D

Comment: Pay attention, you are saving 2 times the model

Comment: Yes, i fixed it. Thank you!